# Can I use ag-grid's old tree data without the enterprise version?

Tags: ag-grid

I'd like to use ag-grid community in plain JS project, which could be commercial soon. I don't know much about license policies.
From [documentation](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-getting-started/) I could suggest that community library is stored here?

```
src="https://unpkg.com/ag-grid/dist/ag-grid.min.noStyle.js
```

Further, I'm intersted in [Tree Data (Legacy)](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-tree/#) feature, which is [free](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-tree-data/). But it's source library looks like:

```
src="https://unpkg.com/ag-grid-enterprise@18.1.1/dist/ag-grid-enterprise.min.js
```

Am I breaking the license rules using this feature? How should I use it correctly? What if I use enterprise lib in non-commercial project, would it work?

Comment: but tree feature still works from community lib
`src="https://unpkg.com/ag-grid/dist/ag-grid.js"`  Is this community version?

Comment: Yes, that's the "community" version (as opposed to enterprise).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can indeed use the [old tree data](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-tree/) implementation without the enterprise version, there's a quote I didn't notice before which sums it up:

https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-tree-data/

> How Tree Data is managed in ag-Grid was changed in ag-Grid v14. This
>   page presents the new way of working with Tree Data. **The old way was
>   part of ag-Grid free**, the new way is part of ag-Grid Enterprise. **The
>   old way is deprecated but you can still use it**, but we will not be
>   enhancing it. For documentation on the older version of the grid prior
>   to v14 see [Tree Data (Legacy)](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-tree).

In their demo of old tree data, the JavaScript file used should really be the "community" version instead of the enterprise one. They just use the enterprise version in all demos to make it easier.

Comment: Provided link now simply goes 404, and the legacy/community feature seems to be disappeared completely in favour of Enterprise one :(

Comment: @Jamby: Thanks. You would have to use an old version of ag-grid (or pay for the new version) in that case. If it's really been removed from the new code (which I didn't check). Here are old docs for it: https://www.ag-grid.com/archive/24.1.0/javascript-grid-tree-data/

Comment: Yeah, I've checked the code and there's only one (unused) reference to the legacy tree data.. The old "getNodeChildDetails" doesn't work anymore. I'll post an answer if manage to get it working in some way. BTW, the link you provided in comment is for ag-grid 24.1.0 which is, at this time, the latest version available (which indeed has no support for legacy tree data).

Comment: Here's some actual docs for the old Tree Data: https://www.ag-grid.com/archive/15.0.0/javascript-grid-tree/#gsc.tab=0